# Android 0 Date picker issue

Tags: android, datepicker

Am compiling my app with android O Api 26,  there is a problem in Date picker
when i set max date to particular date and if am selecting same max date it is crashing.Can any one help?

E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeInMillis must be between the values of getMinDate() and getMaxDate()
                                                                 at android.widget.DayPickerView.setDate(DayPickerView.java:307)
                                                                 at android.widget.DayPickerView.setDate(DayPickerView.java:286)
                                                                 at android.widget.DayPickerView.setDate(DayPickerView.java:275)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.onDateChanged(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:405)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.init(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:376)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePicker.init(DatePicker.java:228)
                                                                 at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onDateChanged(DatePickerDialog.java:151)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.onDateChanged(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:398)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate$1.onDaySelected(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:239)
                                                                 at android.widget.DayPickerView$3.onDaySelected(DayPickerView.java:178)
                                                                 at android.widget.DayPickerPagerAdapter$1.onDayClick(DayPickerPagerAdapter.java:321)
                                                                 at android.widget.SimpleMonthView.onDayClicked(SimpleMonthView.java:1021)
                                                                 at android.widget.SimpleMonthView.onTouchEvent(SimpleMonthView.java:371)
                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11333)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2933)

Comment: please add crash logs

Comment: updated crash logs